# There's a way of responsive a image with html <img src=''> based on size without setting it as background in CSS on a div?

Tags: html, css

I was questioning myself, of all ways that i saw of responsiving images, the better ones were only the "background-url" stuff, centering the image, and "background-cover" making sure that was full size, so with that you don't make the image stretch, but there's a way of doing the same with just  and making the same responsiveness?

It's just a curiosity...

Comment: Look at the `srcset` image attribute. Another option is to use multiple images where you only display one at a time by using CSS media queries.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS property (in conjunction with [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)) to achieve the effect of `background-size: cover` on an `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is using `srcset` also keep in mind you need to put the image of the smallest size in the `src`